# What is the network 169.254.0.0/16 used for in the routing table on a virtual machine?

Tags: networking, routing, subnets

What is the network 169.254.0.0/16 used for in the routing table on a virtual machine (guest: Debian; host: Lubuntu)?

How can I find out  some or all the network interfaces assigned with IP addresses in the range?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Special-use_addresses shows the network is "subnet". Are subnet IP addresses used effectively the same as private IP addresses?

Thanks

The routing table on the host Lubuntu is

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp5s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

The routing table on the guest Debian is:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

Comment: [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

Answer (score 2):

As described in [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) this is link local block:

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block.  As described in    [RFC3927], it is allocated for communication between hosts on a single link.  Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration, such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.

Comment: And by experience on some printers, when a `169.254.0.0/16` addresses is acquired a cabling failure or an issue with the network adapter could be the root cause.